# Firebase Cloud functions schedular

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have a firebase cloud function which needs to be triggered every hour, I see that google has a schedular but I am unable to use it on https functions, if i use a trigger function it takes precendence over the scheduler. Unable to resolve this issue.

So far i have tried creating an https function, with authentication it refuses to work, but if i remove auth it works
I have also created another trigger to check if schedular would take precendence over the trigger but that didnt work either